# NSDateFormatter: stringFromDate and dateFromString not reversible?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I'm having problems using a custom date formatter with `NSDateFormatter` to convert a string into a date. Here's a short example that creates a string from today's date but fails to convert this back to an `NSDate`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"Mdyyyy"];
NSString *example = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];    // e.g., 10292013
NSDate *reverse = [dateFormatter dateFromString:example];  // nil?
```

So basically it seems that `NSDateFormatter` is creating a date string that it itself can't turn back into a `NSDate` using the same format that created the string.

Using `MMddyyyy` as the date string works, although I can't see from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) (which conveniently only goes up to iOS 6.0) why it would matter:

```
month   M   1..2    09  Month - Use one or two for the numerical month, ....
...
day d   1..2    1   Date - Day of the month
```

The reason why I'm trying to use `Mdyyyy` instead of `MMddyyyy` is because it's closer to what `NSDateFormatterShortStyle` returns for my current `NSLocale` (`M/d/yy`).

Perhaps someone might have some insight here as two what I'm doing wrong, or if I'm wrong in my understanding of how this should work. (I know there are a lot of questions here regarding `NSDateFormatter`, but I didn't find one that fits my problem.)

Comment: Mdyyyy is ambiguous as a string ->date mapping.  One cannot tell if "1112013" is Jan 11 or November 1.  Hence NSDateFormatter will not allow it for string ->date.

Comment: @HotLicks, ah of course, and I guess it doesn't care when creating the string that it won't be able to read it back in.... If you care to post an answer, I'll accept this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mdyyyy is ambiguous as a string ->date mapping. One cannot tell if "1112013" is Jan 11 or November 1. Hence NSDateFormatter will not allow it for string ->date.